# pass additional parameters to routes (expressjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, express

Having started working with express recently I have stumbled across the following problem:

The entire logic of my routes is defined in separate files which are then included by means of require(route_name). The respective get / post matches are done as follows:

```
app.get('/', routes.home) etc.
```

The line above implies that routes.home is a function called with the parameters req, res & next.

I have a bunch of utility functions stored in the utils object that I want every route to be able to access. Until now, I've been solving the problem as follows:

```
var utils = ...

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  routes.home(req, res, next, utils);
});
```

Is there a way to tell express that it should pass the utils object as a parameter to every route or generally a better solution to my problem?

Comment: The standard approach would be to have your route files do their own require to pull in utils.  Is there some reason you're not doing that?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with JohnnyHK. And also why do you need to pass res and req twice? Why not do this in your app file:

```
app.get('/', routes.home);
```

And then in your required file something like this:

```
var utils = require('utils')
exports.home = function(req, res){
    //code
}
```

Comment: The reason why I've chosen this way is that utils contains certain modules (e.g. storage) of which only one instance should be available. If it wasn't for that I would be sticking to the procedure you've described above.

Comment: Node docs: Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

Comment: And: If you want to have a module execute code multiple times, then export a function, and call that function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. I've found a solution to my problem by calling an "init(utils)" function on routes I want to have to the utils module.